# Given a spacetime in terms of values of Lorentzian distance, how to determine whether it is flat?

Tags: mathematical-physics, general-relativity, metric-geometry

Yesterday I learned that geometric relations between events can be characterized generally (and up to a common non-zero factor) in terms of their pairwise "[Lorentzian distance, $d_{\ell}$](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lorentzian+distance%22)", which satisfies for any three events, $\mathsf A$, $\mathsf B$, $\mathsf Q$

- if $\mathsf A$ and $\mathsf B$ are space-like or light-like related to each other then $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~] = d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~] = 0$; and otherwise:
- if $\mathsf A$ and $\mathsf B$ are time-like related to each other then $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~]$ may be zero, finite, or infinite;
- if $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~]$ is finite then $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf B, \mathsf A~] = 0$; and
- if $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~]$, $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf Q~]$ and $d_{\ell}[~\mathsf B, \mathsf Q~]$ are all finite then the inverse triangle relation holds:

$$\left( \frac{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~]}{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf Q~]} \lt 1 \right) \text{ and } \left( \frac{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf B, \mathsf Q~]}{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf Q~]} \lt 1 \right) \implies \left( \frac{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf B~]}{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf Q~]} + \frac{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf B, \mathsf Q~]}{d_{\ell}[~\mathsf A, \mathsf Q~]} \le 1 \right).$$

**Questions:**

Given a spacetime $\mathscr S$ as a set of events together with their values of Lorentzian distance, $\mathscr S := (\mathcal S, d_{\ell})$, are there conditions (on set $\mathcal S$ and/or on the pairwise values $d_{\ell}$) under which it is possible to determine whether or not $\mathscr S$ is a "[flat spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_spacetime)"?

If spacetime $\mathscr S$ satisfies such conditions, how exactly would be determined whether $\mathscr S$ is flat, or not?

And if $\mathscr S$ had thereby be found to be flat, then how can the corresponding values of "[spacetime intervals, $s^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_intervals_in_flat_space)" for all pairs of events in set $\mathcal S$ be expressed in terms of the given Lorentzian distance values $d_{\ell}$ ?

Comment: This seems more like a math question than a physics question. For me flat space time basically means the Riemann tensor is zero.

Comment: Agreed. A zero Riemann tensor is what physicists mean by a flat space. This question seems to be concerned with a mathematical function ([Lorentzian distance](http://www.ugr.es/~ahurtado/PDF/proceeding.pdf)) that isn't used in physics.

Comment: @Horus: "_more like a math question than a physics question._" -- I take that as a complaint and I'll add the appropriate tag ("[tag:mathematical-physics]") so users who opt not to be bothered with such questions won't complain anymore. "_For me flat space time basically means the Riemann tensor is zero._" -- Oh, this "[_Riemann tensor_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor)" seems an awfully mathematical object indeed; involving coordinates and whatnot. I was rather thinking of MTW Box 13.1 and [generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula#Generalizations).

Comment: @John Rennie: "_A zero Riemann tensor is what physicists mean by a flat space._" -- MTW Box 13.1 illustrates that physicists can at least **express** what they mean by "flat space" (or by "flat spacetime") without any (explicit) reference to (values of the) "_Riemann tensor_" at all; but instead: referring to distances, and [certain expressions in terms of distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry_problem#Cayley.E2.80.93Menger_determinants).

Comment: @John Rennie: "_[...] a mathematical function (Lorentzian distance) that isn't used in physics._" -- How do you suppose that physicists express geometric relations between events instead? (Surely not through coordinate assignments?? ...)

Comment: @user12262: Where exactly in box 13.1 is the part about flatness?

Comment: @MBN: "_Where exactly in box 13.1 is the part about flatness?_" -- Quoting the footnote of the second page of box 13.1 (p. 307 in my copy): "The extended Hero[n]-Tartaglia formula [...] in a locally Euclidean or Lorentz space of $n$ dimensions [...]". Note also the Cayley-Menger determinant appearing in Synge, GR, ch. xi, §8, "A five-point curvature detector".

Comment: @user12262: That is not related to flatness.

Comment: @MBN: "_That is not related to flatness._" -- Do you claim specificly that "3-dimensional Euclidean space is _not related to flatness_"? And that "(3+1)-dimensional Lorentz space is _not related to flatness_"? Or what else specificly do you mean by "_that_ which is _not related to flatness_"??

Comment: @user12262: Four points in 3D Euclidean space can be in a 2D plane or not, to tell you can compute the volume of the tetrahedron the form, if it is zero they lie in a plane, if not they don't. That is something completely different from what the curvature of the space is.

Comment: You don't need a coordinate system to talk about a tensor, and the Riemann tensor is zero or not regardless of whether or which coordinate system you choose. Usually a manifold is defined in terms of coordinate charts, but that's not where the experimental predictions come from so it is not required.

Comment: @MBN: "_Four points in 3D Euclidean space can be in a 2D plane or not_" -- That's right. Of course, four points in any Euclidean space of dimension 3 **or larger** can be in a 2D plane (a.k.a. "be plane to each other") or not. Similarly, three points any Euclidean space of dimension 2 **or larger** can be ("one-dimensionally") straight to each other, or not. And five points in any Euclidean space of dimension 4 **or larger** can be: "flat to each other", or not. And five points in any generally curved space of dimension 3 **or larger** can be: "flat to each other", or not. And so on.

Comment: @Timaeus: "_You don't need a coordinate system to talk about a tensor_" -- At least for the [Riemann tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) we do (more or less explicitly) because the Riemann tensor takes two "tangent vectors" as arguments which are defined and distinguished by means of coordinates, or some abstraction thereof; and not, for instance, two equivalence classes of [path graphs **in the given set** $\mathcal S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph). "_coordinate charts [...] that's not where the experimental predictions come from_" -- Hear, hear!

Comment: @user12262: Obviously the word "flat" here is used in a different context and meaning. It doesn't related to the curvature of the space. It expresses a relation between point, whether they belong in a common plane and so on.

Comment: @MBN: "_[Vanishing Cayley-Menger determinants  aren't] related to the curvature of the space._" -- Read up on [S. L. Kokkendorff, "_Gram Matrix Analysis of Finite Distance Spaces in Constant Curvature_"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00454-004-0806-2): "The lowest-order term in an power series expansion of the Gram determinant $\text{det}[~\mathbf G_{\kappa}~]$ in (sectional curvature value) $\kappa$ is proportional to the Cayley-Menger determinant $\text{det}[~\mathbf CM~]$." [continued]

Comment: MBN: "_Obviously the word "flat" here is used in a different context, meaning._" -- That's far from obvious to me, since I have no idea what you mean by "_flat_" in turn; in particular, how you might propose to determine whether or not "_the Riemann tensor is zero_ (at one point, or at all points)", if that's what you had in mind. If you claim that your notion of "flat" is inequvalent to the vanishing of (all) applicable Cayley-Menger determinants then **prove it**. p.s. [My answer to "_How to measure the curvature of the space-time?_" (PSE/q/109731)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/109751)

Comment: @user12262: Your question is about how to determine if a given space-time is flat or not. The box in the book you referred to talks about whether a number of points lie flat in a plane or not. These are two different things that you are confusing. And it is obvious, because one is about the space-time the other is about a set of points. Take Euclidean space, it is flat i.e. has zero curvature, yet you can have four points in it that do not lie flat in a plane, right?

Comment: @MBN: "_Your question is about how to determine if a given space-time is flat or not._" -- Right; where S-T is understood as having "3+1" dimensions, as usual. "_The box in the book [...] talks about whether a number of points lie flat in a plane or not._" -- Since you had asked me above, I was pointing you to **the footnote** ("_* If the distance [...]_") of Box 13.1 ("Metric distilled from distances") of Misner, Thorne, Wheeler "Gravitation". I urge you to read it. This footnote shows a general formula in terms of the integer variable $n\ge 2$. Of interest for my question is the case $n=5$.

Comment: @MBN: "_Take Euclidean space_" ... understood to be "3D", as usual ... "_it's flat i.e. has zero curvature_" -- Correct. This refers to the case $n=4$, namely that for any $5$ points in 3D Euclidean space the corresponding Cayley-Menger determinant (in terms of the 10 distance values between these 5 points) vanishes. "_yet you can have four points in it that do not lie flat in a plane, right?_" -- correct: in 3D Euclidean space we have plenty of quadruples (sets of $4$ points) whose C-M determinant (in terms of the 6 distance values between these 4 points) does not vanish. But [... contd.]

Comment: But in 3D Euclidean space, corresponding to case $n=4$, we cannot have $5$ points at all such that their Cayley-Menger determinant would not vanish. (Regardless of whether or not the Cayley-Menger determinant for any $4$ among them vanishes.)

Comment: You still don't get it. Flatness of the spacetime (no matter what dimension) and flatness as configuration of points in a spacetime are two different things that you confuse.

Comment: @MBN: "_Flatness of the spacetime (no matter what dimension) and flatness as configuration of points in a spacetime are two different things that you confuse_" -- It seems that you still haven't gotten it. If you claim that "_flatness of a spacetime_" is a notion different from "_flatness of each configuration of sufficiently many ($n+1$) points in a spacetime_", such that they might possibly be confused by someone who doesn't know or understand their difference, **then prove** that there exists such a supposed difference; demonstrate such a difference **explicitly**. Else: use Ockham's razor.

Comment: @user12262: I've already given you an example. Take 3d Euclidean space, it is flat (has zero curvature). On the other hand you can take four point, the vertices of a pyramid, they are not flat in a plane. If one is flat and the other is not, obviously the two notions cannot be the same.

Comment: @MBN: "_I've already given you an example. Take 3d Euclidean space, it is flat (has zero curvature)._" -- I've already answered to your example: yes, 3d Euclidean space is flat **this means** that the Cayley-Menger determinant of any **5 points** is vanishing. (And that this corresponds to the case $n = 4$ in the MTW/Blumenthal definition.) "_On the other hand you can take four point, the vertices of a pyramid, they are not flat in a plane._" -- And I've already agreed to that. Note that five is larger than four, please.

Comment: @user12262: Take the same example and change the usual metric to something else, then the space will not be flat (non-zero curvature) and the determinant of any 5 points will vanish (it is the same, no change here).

Comment: @MBN: "_Take the same example and change the usual metric to sth. else,_" -- If you're suggesting not to consider the [**metric space** which is called "3D Euclidean"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) (namely with distance ratios such that the C-M det. for any 5 points vanishes), but to consider some other **metric space**, then I can try to accommodate your suggestion, but I'd consider this **another example** of a metric space. Otherwise, please define what you mean by "_the usual metric_" and "_some other metric_" and explain how this might relate to distance values.

Comment: The volume of the object with 5 points as vertices will be zero (that depends only on the dimension), but the space sill not be flat. A more visual example would be a curved surface and four points on it.

Comment: @MBN: "_a curved surface and four points on it._" -- Excellent: work out this simpler case ($n = 3$) first. Let's compare a 2D plane, and a (curved) 2D spherical surface. Distances in the plane should be obvious; distances in the spherical surface are arclengths of great circle segments (for any two points always "the short one"). In the spherical surface it's easy to find four points whose $n = 3$ C-M det. is non-zero; just don't place all four points along the same great circle. In contrast, in the plane **you won't find any** four points whose $n = 3$ C-M det. is non-zero. Now generalize.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a flat spacetime where every pair of events can be connected by both a spacelike path and by a timelike path. So in that case your "definition" would require that the distance between every pair of events is zero in that case. And that assignment of zero always works for any spacetime. So if you are claiming uniqueness you are wrong. We can just assert that every spacetime has a distance function that always assigns zero to any pair of events. You can't possibly get any information from that.

If instead I look at the spirit of your rules, many of the other properties seemed to be based on properties not obeyed by that spacetime. And it makes me think the whole theory was only designed to apply to some subset of spacetimes, probably time oriented ones. And that's a global property, so not accessible to experimental validation, so this is a math question.

And then it relates to the common concrete definition where the distance is just the supremum of zero and the lengths of all future directed (so only for time oriented spacetimes) causal paths from A to B.

Comment: Timaeus: "_a flat spacetime where every pair of events can be connected by both a spacelike path and by a timelike path._" -- Well, that's perhaps not included in the notion of "flat spacetime" which I intended and linked to [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space). So: can you please suggest some terminology to express "my sharper" notion of flatness? (You know: the one which goes nicely with [being characterized by vanishing Cayley-Menger determinants](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/166354).) If you do, I'd accept your answer here; and ask again more correctly.

Comment: Timaeus: "_your "definition" [...]_" -- I accept that your example exposes me having been careless in phrasing/ordering the properties of "Lorentzian distance" listed in the OP. (Of course, I tend to use the words "space-like"or "time-like" as referring to [causal relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Causal_relations) between events which are presumably mutually exclusive; and decidedly not in terms of "tangent spaces" or somesuch.) "_a global property, so not accessible to experimental validation, so this is a math question._" -- I strongly disagree; but I added a tag.

Comment: @user12262 GR is a local theory. A manifold with a metric tensor and a stress tensor that satisfies the Einstein Equation (a local equation) is good. There are solutions that locally look just like local versions of Minkowski space, including having a metric where every event has a neighborhood where the metric is the literally the exact Minkowski metric in the neighborhood, $\mathbb R^4/\mathbb Z^4$ is an example. For any experiment you do in Minkowski spacetime, one of these other spacetimes has an equivalent experiment that looks exactly the same for the local observations in the experiment

Comment: The notion of flatness, like all the physical notions in GR, is a local thing. And it just means the rank four Riemann tensor is zero. You could be flat at a point or flat in a neighborhood, or flat in all neighborhoods, which is then flat. Which doesn't give you that you are time orientable, you need to assume that if you want that. Most global causality conditions are only defined for time orientable manifolds. And like all global properties it is not so directly connected to experiments which are local. There are many flat spacetimes and only one of them is Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: Your cited method of determinants first starts out assuming a global time orient ability and then goes on to assume a foliation made up of hyperplanes. It basically assume $\mathbb R^4$ as the topology and then goes even farther to throw a global interval on the whole thing. Even if you had a manifold and it was $\mathbb R^4$ topologically and has a metric, that's a local metric you have to show that from that you can or can't get a global function and then that it has some property. And experimentally, whatever you measured in MS I could make a manifold that wasn't $\mathbb R^4$ that agreed

Comment: Timaeus: "_method of determinants first starts out assuming global time orientability_"$$d_{\ell}\in\mathbb R,$$ "_goes on to assume a foliation made up of hyperplanes._" $$\mathcal{P,Q}\subset\mathcal S :$$ 
$$\forall\mathsf{A,B}\in\mathcal P : d_{\ell}[~\mathsf{A,B}~]=0,\qquad\forall\mathsf{J,K}\in\mathcal Q : d_{\ell}[~\mathsf{J,K}~]=0,$$ $$ 
\forall\mathsf A\in\mathcal P\exists\mathsf J\in\mathcal Q : \forall\mathsf K \in\mathcal Q\exists\mathsf B\in\mathcal P : d_{\ell}[~\mathsf{A,J}~]~d_{\ell}[~\mathsf{B,K}~]\gt 0\text{ or } d_{\ell}[~\mathsf{J,A}~]~d_{\ell}[~\mathsf{K,B}~] \gt 0$$etc.

Comment: Timaeus: "_GR is a local theory. A manifold with a metric tensor and_" ... let's not even worry about variational calculus ("dynamics") ... "_is good._" -- Not quite. The 1 % genius of GR is the assertion that ["_All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences {such as} encounters between two or more {...} material points_"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity). The remaining 99 % is putting this to concrete use, and contesting undefined uses of the words "_local_", or "_neighborhood_".